# How to make clang not substitute #define macro

Tags: c++, clang

I'm calling the `Success` method on the pointer `result`, but clang substitutes the macro `Success` from `X11.h`:

```
/home/dev/common/src/flutter_orwell_plugin.cc:42:10: error: expected unqualified-id
        result->Success(&response);                                     
                ^                                                       
/usr/include/X11/X.h:350:21: note: expanded from macro 'Success'        
#define Success            0    /* everything's okay */
```

I can't change the name "Success", it's from the library. Why this is happening?

Comment: I believe this is one of the reasons we use a different naming convention for Macros as opposed to function names. Is the function name from the library or the macro?

Comment: `#undef` it, or rename the function

Comment: Another possibility to avoid that problem is to split files so that you don't need both include from the same source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [undef](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#.23undef_directive) directive to remove a previously-defined macro. For example:

```
#undef Success
return result->Success(&response);
```